# Opening wallet.dat in python, using bsddb3

Tags: wallet.dat

I'm trying to open wallet.dat using the bsddb3 module for Python 2.7.

```
db = bsddb3.btopen("wallet.dat", "r")
```

contents of db:

```
{'main': '\x00\x00\x00\x02'}
```

I have to Which is almost nothing.

```
ls -l wallet.dat -> 72K
```

I though I could view information about the wallet, is there problem with the version of bsddb or this line of code?

Answer (score 2):

open the database like this:

```
from bsddb.db import *

db = DB()
r= db.open("wallet.dat", "main", DB_BTREE, DB_RDONLY)

print "%s" % (db.items())
```

Comment: This does not work under python 3.

Comment: @d-r yes, you need to use `from bsddb3.db import *` and parenthesis around the print